# derangement-like problem with hats and people

Tags: combinatorics

There are seven people, each with their differently-colored hat. They go into a room, and get their hats shuffled then given back to them. How many ways are there such that none of the first three people get their hats back?

I tried approaching this problem with constructive counting. The first hat can go to $6$ people, the second to $5$, the third to $4$. The fourth hat can go to $4$ people, the fifth to three, etc.

So it would be $ 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 4! = 2880$, but the answer is $3216$. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are undercounting. For example, when the first person receives second person's hat, the second person can take any of the remaining six hats and not just five.

One of the straightforward solutions is to apply Principle of Inclusion Exclusion. Number of permissible arrangements are given by,

$ \displaystyle 7! - \left[{3 \choose 1}  6! - {3 \choose 2} 5! + {3 \choose 3} 4!\right] = 3216$

$7!$ is unrestricted number of arrangements and the second term in $ [ ~ ]$ is number of arrangements where *at least* one of the first three get back their own hat.

---

Though tedious, if you are counting directly, find a logical way to come up with cases so counting becomes easier. One approach would be as follows.

Say, set of three hats that belong to first three is $S$. Cases -

$i)$ None of the three hats are from set $S$
$ii)$ One of the hats is from set $S$
$iii)$ Two of the hats are from set $S$
$iv)$ All three hats are from set $S$

Comment: Thank you! I assume the PIE is complementary counting?

Comment: In this case, yes because we are subtracting from $7!$ all cases where at least one of the first three  get their own hat back. I also outlined a direct counting method for you in the end. You can try and ask me questions if you get stuck.